# python vscode typehints for conftest fixtures

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, conftest

For my tests I defined a lot of fixtures and also added typehints to them. All of this fixtures are defined in the `conftest.py` and are "magically" available in all of the test :)
But sadly vscode can't show information (signatures, typehints, etc) for this fixtures when used in my tests. Is there any way to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickmillerdev.pytest-fixtures ? This is a VS Code plugin which specifically demoes using conftest.py-defined fixtures in other test scripts.